# How to get unlimited query list form AWS amplify datastore and loading data in real time in recyclerView just like youtube,twitter,instagram feed?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, api, graphql, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify as my app backend(GraphQL api).Using below method we can get fixed list of data and we can set that to recycler view. But I want unlimited scroll in my feed like other apps and real-time data loading.If you have any knowledge about this or you if you know about source to study this please help.

```
Amplify.API.query(
    ModelQuery.list(Todo.class, Todo.NAME.contains("first")),
    response -> {
        for (Todo todo : response.getData()) {
            Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", todo.getName());
        }
    },
    error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Query failure", error)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paginating the data can be achieved by setting a limit and using nextToken in the query function. More information about it can be found here - https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-graphql/graphql-pagination/q/platform/js/
Each time the user reaches the last item in the loaded list it should fire new query and therefore creating the 'infinite scroll'.

Comment: Thank you but can you help me how to use @Searchable to search something in aws data store

Comment: @nothing searchable is not compatible with DataStore. Behind searchable aws is using 'opensearch' that works with dynamodb. In order to use it you will have to sync dataStore data to dynamodb. To create dynamodb with searchable please check this documentation - https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/overview/